# Closed-Form Formula For Higher Powers of an Algebraic Number

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{K}$
  be a finite-degree algebraic field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $\xi$
  be algebraic over $\mathbb{K}$
  of degree $d$
  minimal polynomial: $$X^{d}-\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}\alpha_{k}X^{k}\in\mathbb{K}\left[X\right]$$
 i.e., so that: $$\xi^{d}=\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}\alpha_{k}\xi^{k}$$
 Letting $m$
  be a positive integer, one can use the above identity to re-write $\xi^{m+d}$
  as a linear combination of $1,\xi,\xi^{2},\ldots,\xi^{d-1}$. Namely, for each $m$, there are polynomials $$P_{m}\left(\alpha_{k},\alpha_{k-1},\ldots,\alpha_{k-m}\right)$$
 so that $$\xi^{d+m}=\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}P_{m}\left(\alpha_{k},\alpha_{k-1},\ldots,\alpha_{k-m}\right)\xi^{k}$$
 with the convention that $\alpha_{j}=0$
  for all $j\leq-1$. Doing the computations by hand for the first few values of $m$ gives:

$P_{0}=\alpha_{k}$

$P_{1}=\alpha_{k-1}+\alpha_{k}\alpha_{d-1}$

$P_{2}=\alpha_{k-2}+\alpha_{k-1}\alpha_{d-1}+\alpha_{k}\left(\alpha_{d-1}^{2}+\alpha_{d-2}\right)$

$P_{3}=\alpha_{k-3}+\alpha_{k-2}\alpha_{d-1}+\alpha_{k-1}\left(\alpha_{d-1}^{2}+\alpha_{d-2}\right)+\alpha_{k}\left(\alpha_{d-1}^{3}+2\alpha_{d-1}\alpha_{d-2}+\alpha_{d-3}\right)$

Clearly, there are polynomials:

$Q_{0}=1$

$Q_{1}=\alpha_{d-1}$

$Q_{2}=\alpha_{d-1}^{2}+\alpha_{d-2}$

$Q_{3}=\alpha_{d-1}^{3}+2\alpha_{d-1}\alpha_{d-2}+\alpha_{d-3}$

So that: 
$$P_{m}=\alpha_{k-m}Q_{0}+\alpha_{k-\left(m-1\right)}Q_{1}+\alpha_{k-\left(m-2\right)}Q_{2}+\cdots+\alpha_{k}Q_{m}=\sum_{j=0}^{m}\alpha_{k-m+j}Q_{j}$$
 at least for $m\leq d-1$. 
My question is: what is the general formula for $Q_{j}$? And what is the general formula for $P_{m}$, including when $m\geq d$?

Comment: Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n$ the minimal polynomial of $\xi$, $\frac{f(x)}{x^N} = \sum_{n=0}^N a_{N-n} x^{-n}, \frac{x^N}{f(x)} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k x^{-k}$ and $g_{N+m}(x) = x^{N+m}-f(x)\sum_{k=0}^m c_k x^{m-k}$ [then $\deg(g_{N+m}) = N-1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) and
$\xi^{N+m} = g_{N+m}(\xi)$

Comment: I'm specifically looking for the coordinates of $\xi^{d+m}$ (where $m\geq0$) as an element of $\mathbb{K}\left(\xi\right)$ with respect to the basis $\left\{ 1,\xi,\ldots,\xi^{d-1}\right\}$.

Comment: This is what I answered to

Comment: Your formula yields $\xi^{N+m}=\xi^{N+m}-f\left(\xi\right)\sum_{k=0}^{m}c_{k}\xi^{m-k}$. How do I use that to compute the coefficients $b_{m,0},\ldots,b_{m,d-1}\in\mathbb{K}$ so that $\xi^{N+m}=\sum_{n=0}^{d-1}b_{m,n}\xi^{n}$?

Comment: The $c_k$ are the convolution inverse of the $a_{N-n}$, there is a simple recursive formula to find them, they also have a simple expression in term of the roots of $f$. You are interested only in the $N$ first coefficients of $x^{N+m}-f(x)\sum_{k=0}^m c_k x^{m-k}$ (the other are $0$ )

Comment: Okay. Where can I go to find the expression for the $c_{k}$ in terms of the roots of $f$?

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition $\frac{f(x)}{x^N} =\frac{1}{g(x^{-1})}= \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{g'(1/\alpha_j)}{1-\alpha_j x^{-1}}, g(z) = \prod_{j=1}^N(1-\alpha_j z)$ plus geometric series

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!

Comment: Then you'll need to see the multiplication by $\xi$ as a multiplication by a matrix in the ring and $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra $\mathbb{Q}[\xi]$ whose basis are the $\xi^j$. It suffices to diagonalize this matrix for ...